# Altair: How to use interval selection on candlestick chart (ie: a layered chart)

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to replicate the following stacked chart for which the domain of the top chart can be selected by interacting with the bottom chart, but with a candlestick chart (which is a layered chart):

(example code for below is here: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interval_selection.html)
[image]

I can't get it to work with layered charts (https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/candlestick_chart.html). Is it possible to scrub by date in this way with layered charts? Thanks.

This is what I have tried:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.ohlc()
brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])
open_close_color = alt.condition("datum.open <= datum.close", alt.value("green"), alt.value("firebrick"))

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    alt.X('date:T', axis=alt.Axis(format='%m/%d', title='Date in 2009')),
    color=open_close_color
).properties(width=600, height=400)

rule = base.mark_rule().encode(
    alt.Y('low:Q', title='Price', scale=alt.Scale(domain=brush, zero=False)),
    alt.Y2('high:Q')
)

bar = base.mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('open:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=brush, zero=False)),
    alt.Y2('close:Q')
)

candles = rule + bar

lower = base.properties(
    height=60
).add_selection(brush)

candles & lower
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Vega-Lite spec and interactive chart via the Vega Editor: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/2e5d94af2d36ee770b980f648774b865/vega-lite-interactive-candlestick-spec.json

This was created this using the following python/altair code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.ohlc()
open_close_color = alt.condition("datum.open <= datum.close",
                                 alt.value("#06982d"),
                                 alt.value("#ae1325"))
brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    alt.X('date:T',
          axis=alt.Axis(
              format='%m/%d',
              labelAngle=-45,
              title='Date in 2009'
          )
    ),
    color=open_close_color
).properties(
    width=600,
)

rule = base.mark_rule().encode(
    alt.Y(
        'low:Q',
        title='Price',
        scale=alt.Scale(zero=False),
    ),
    alt.Y2('high:Q')
)

bar = base.mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('open:Q'),
    alt.Y2('close:Q')
)

lower = alt.layer(rule, bar, height=60).add_selection(brush)

upper = (rule + bar).encode(
    alt.X('date:T', scale=alt.Scale(domain=brush))
)

# (upper & lower)                         # display the charts
print((upper & lower).to_json(indent=2))  # get the vega-lite spec
```

I had some issue with the interactivity working in my Jupyter setup, but when I copied the spec into the Vega Editor it worked. It could be related to the version of Vega-Lite (4.8.1 in my setup, 4.16.7 in the Vega Editor).

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. I have only used Altair (not Vega) -- so do I need to install Vega and pass the dict to it to plot? Tx

Comment: What are you trying to do with the plot? If you want it to be interactive within Altair, I'm not sure what will work. I'm thinking the version of Vega-Lite used by Altair has an issue with selections across layers. If you want to get the plot from Vega-Lite, you can either use the Vega-Lite editor I linked to, or you can use the some vega-embed code to embed it into a web page. https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/getting_started.html#embed.  Note: With vega-embed code I changed the version of vega-lite to 4.8.1, the interactivity stopped working.

Comment: Altair is essentially a wrapper for Vega-Lite. It creates a Vega-Lite json spec. I was using to_dict to get the spec, but I found a better way with print((upper & lower).to_json(indent=2))

Comment: I think I will end up outputting to a web page so I will check out your vega embed link. Thanks again.