# Sort by multiple columns in Altair

Tags: python, altair

In the following, I'd like to sort first by count (which works in the example below), but then also by group name (so for the two items with a count of 1, B should be listed before D):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col':['D','A','C','A','C','B','C']})
alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='count()',
    y=alt.Y('col', sort='-x')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
test1 = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='count():Q',
    y=alt.Y('col:N', sort=['-x', 'col'])
)
```

[image]

But you can definitely manually force the sort by passing a list, so you can wrangle an ordered list like this and pass it to altair:

```
manual_ordered = data['col'].value_counts().reset_index()
manual_ordered = manual_ordered.sort_values(['col', 'index'], ascending=[False, True])

    manual = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
        x='count()',
        y=alt.Y('col', sort=manual_ordered)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, let me know if you have any ideas on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63515434/9448637   :)

Comment: Yeah, when giving a list as argument to sort, that means you name elements explicitly. I have tried that as well. Pre-calculating that order is a nice idea, I'll do it like that if no one comes up with a altair/vega-interna way, thanks!