# Altair use in VS Code with Interactive Python Extension broken

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, altair

Today I tried to create an Altair chart in VS Code and it would not display.  The code either runs with no output or returns the following error. Another friend has the same issue starting today.

```
Error loading script: Script error for "vega-util", needed by: vega-embed https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

I can still save charts using altair-saver.  Are there any other uses of VS Code with Altair having an issue?

Using https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_line_chart.html has the issue.

```
# %%
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(100)
source = pd.DataFrame({
  'x': x,
  'f(x)': np.sin(x / 5)
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='x',
    y='f(x)'
)
```

Comment: I just tried and also got no output (on both your provided example and my own plots). :(

Comment: I put the code in jupyter notebook and export it as python script, it both works well and shows the chart. If you choose 'run python file in terminal', there's nothing showed. You should click 'run cell' to enter interactive mode, the chart will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [vega/vega-embed#557](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed/issues/557); the error was due to a faulty vega-embed release which has now been fixed. Clear your javascript cache and it should load the updated version of vega-embed and work properly again.

Comment: thanks for your fix here. Would you be able to taka e quick look at my question here and let me know if its possible to do in Altair? Tx https://stackoverflow.com/q/63515434/9448637